# Showing a reduction between decision problems

Tags: logic, satisfiability

I asked a similar question on cs.stackexchange, but I'd like to ask it a tad more specifically, and thought this would be a better place for it. I'm looking through a text on logic, and the problem is basically as follows:

Suppose we have an algorithm for deciding wether a sentence A implies a sentence B (A->B). Show that we can use this to determine if a given sentence A is satisfiable. I'm sort of lost on how to do this, and even a hint would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the setting, presumably there is some background theory $T$.

A sentence $\varphi$ is satisfiable if $\lnot\varphi$ is not a theorem.    And $\lnot\varphi$ is not a theorem precisely if the implication $X\to \lnot\varphi$ fails to hold, where $X$ is your favourite always true sentence. If we have an algorithm for determining whether an implication holds, that algorithm is also an algorithm for determining whether an implication fails to hold.

Comment: My suggestion along these lines would be $(P \lor\lnot P)\to\lnot\varphi$.  For no good reason I am using $\varphi$ instead of $A$.

Comment: Sorry I was slightly confused reading this for a second. Thanks so much. I know it's pretty trivial, but I was just unsure

Comment: You are  welcome. One thing I am still unsure of is context, presentations of logic tend to differ, and I don't even know whether you are working in propositional logic or the predicate calculus. The answer (apart from the initial comment about $T$) would not change very much if I knew.